# Why data model is not updated when ListView row with a CheckBox gets off-screen?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

While this is the behaviour that I want, could someone explain me why does it happen?

I have a `ListView` with custom rows consisting of a `CheckBox` and a `TextView`. Here is row layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/shop_list_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_list_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample text"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I have this simple data model (omitted some methods and fields), basically a shop with a name and selection state:

```
public class ShopListItem {

    //name of the shop
    private String name;

    //shop selection state
    private boolean isSelected;

    public ShopListItem(String shopKey, String name, boolean isSelected) {
        this.shopKey = shopKey;
        this.name = name;
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selectionState) {
        this.isSelected = selectionState;
    }
}
```

And here is relevant code from my custom `ArrayAdapter`:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        // Temporary view to be returned as converterView
        View view;

        // Checking if view is reused or not
        if (convertView == null) { //new view is generated

            // Inflate new view and associate its views with viewHodler
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_shop_list, parent, false);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.shopNameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop_list_textView);
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.shop_list_checkbox);

            // Asign check change listener
            viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    Log.i("i", "isChecked value is: "+isChecked+", buttonView.isChecked() value is: "+buttonView.isChecked());

                    // Get reference to the shop (data model) of checked row
                    ShopListItem shop = (ShopListItem) viewHolder.checkBox.getTag();

                    // Update selection state in data model
                    shop.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                    listSelections(shopsArrayList);

                }
            });


            // Store viewHolder inside temporary view
            view.setTag(viewHolder);

            // Store reference to a shop (data model) of this row in the checkbox reference
            viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(shopsArrayList.get(position));

        } else {  //existing view reused

            // Assign view from adapter to temporary view
            view = convertView;

            // Get viewholder from view which was stored while generating new view
            ViewHolder storedHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

            //Store reference to a shop (data model) of this row in the checkbox reference
            storedHolder.checkBox.setTag(shopsArrayList.get(position));

        }

        // Get viewholder from view (from new view or converview)
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        // Populate holder references with data from shops array list
        holder.shopNameTextView.setText(shopsArrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(shopsArrayList.get(position).isSelected());

        //return view
        return view;

    }
```

The mystery lies within `OnCheckedChangeListener`. Whenever I click the checkbox of first row, listener receives correct state and updates first item of the shops array list (either to true or false). But, if I leave first checkbox checked and scroll list down, as soon as first row gets off-screen,  `OnCheckedChangeListener` is called with the state `false`, but first item of the shops array list is not updated to `false`. Why is this happening? Why it gets updated only when click the box, but not when its called due being hidden?

Comment: Guys, I forgot to mention, that when I scroll list back up, the first item stays selected - everything is working correctly. I just dont understand why my arraylist is not being updated to `false` when row view is being utilized and `OnCheckedChangeListener` is called with `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you click the checkbox the `OnCheckedChangeListener` is being activated. When you scroll down or up the **OTHER** `OnCheckedChangeListener` is being called for the **NEW ROW** that is coming to the screen. The `OnCheckedChangeListener` of the hidden line is not being called.

In your case, I suppose, you are getting the checkbox value of the new line coming onto the screen and it gives you confusion. Try to distinguish which shop object is being referred to in your `OnCheckedChangeListener's` line:

```
ShopListItem shop = (ShopListItem) viewHolder.checkBox.getTag();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one flag to maintain checked data item in your Data List >

```
 public boolean isSelected() {
  return selected;
 }
 public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
  this.selected = selected;
 }
```

And add code for checkbox in your getView() of Adapter

```
 @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ViewHolder holder = null;
   Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

   if (convertView == null) {
   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info, null);

   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
   holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
   convertView.setTag(holder);

    holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {  
     public void onClick(View v) {  
      CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;  
      Country country = (Country) cb.getTag();  
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
       "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
       " is " + cb.isChecked(), 
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      country.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
     }  
    });  
   } 
   else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

   Country country = countryList.get(position);
   holder.code.setText(" (" +  country.getCode() + ")");
   holder.name.setText(country.getName());
   holder.name.setChecked(country.isSelected());
   holder.name.setTag(country);

   return convertView;

  }
```

for more information please see below Link:

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Answer (score 0):

As you scroll the list, first item goes off screen. When item goes off getView is called and view is utilized. You need to keep state of that particular object to properly show at UI Level

Comment: State of that particular object is being kept - it stays selected when I scroll back up! I just dont understand why item in the ArrayList doesnt get changed to `false` when it gets off-screen.

Comment: Why it should get changed.I mean when you are storing the state this is the thing you are wanting

Comment: When I deselect the box, `OnCheckedChangeListener` is called with `false ` and array is updated to false. When I scroll selected box out of the screen, `OnCheckedChangeListener` is called again with `false`, but array is not updated to false, it stays `true`. I dont understand this inconsistency.

Comment: well you need to check when you are deselecting, are you even updating array or not?

Comment: I am, chere is the line: shop.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

Comment: But this line does not work when called due off-screen.

Comment: buttonView.isPressed() try this

Comment: This doesnt answer my question :(